# Remote Access to Windows Server 2003 while in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop-services, safe-mode

I have a Windows 2003 server. This server has experienced errors necessitating a restore procedure carried out in Safe Mode. However, the server is located in a remote location.

How can I ensure that I will have remote access to my server after restarting it in Safe Mode?

Comment: To restart in safe mode, TeamViewer is the best.. Since you do have RDP you may be able to install TW and check... https://www.teamviewer.com/en/res/pdf/TeamViewer7_Manual_RemoteControl_EN.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to be answered as "NO" here:
[Remote restart into safe mode? (windows)](https://serverfault.com/questions/55063/remote-restart-into-safe-mode-windows) 
and f.e. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-networking/trying-to-use-remote-desktop-to-connect-to-a/16863a8f-f6e3-43d9-91f8-6c8fb9a1d077

However you could fire up your test machine to write the steps needed to be changed in safe mode and execute that script on startup event.

As this is remote do heavy testing beforehand.

For the future you might be interested in setting up something like this:

I have seen it in some schools and we use a similiar setup currently:

Set bios/uefi to boot via network first, let the pxe boot define default to the harddrive you use for booting, in case of inicident you redefine the default for that specific mac/server/computer (you do have inventory "lists" for that right?) and can restore a previous backup and/or add files for automatic executing after normal boot.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to connect to a Windows 2003 server in safe-mode without 3rd party software.

When entering safe-mode WITH NETWORKING, the OS will still block RDP connections.

I've seen that VNC has been suggested as a 3rd party work-around but I can't confirm that it will work.